# UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'present'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to present a view controller when I select a row in a tableView which is inside a UICollectionViewCell.I didn't use storyboards in my project. I tried to call 'present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)' inside 'didSelectRowAt indexPath:...' but I get an error 'SecondPageCollectionViewCell' has no member 'present', I also tried to perform a segue , but I still get the same error. How could I present another View Controller when I tap on a row?

```
class SecondPageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource   {

let viewController = ViewController()
let tableView = UITableView()
...

 override func awakeFromNib() {
 ...
 }

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row \(indexPath.row)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allUsers.descriptions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return frame.height - secondViewheight

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   ...
}

}
```

Comment: ViewController is capable to present so you can also try to present on widow!

Comment: you can either use segues on storyboard or write an explicit _did-select-row-at-index-path_ method to present new content – literally millions of examples are around the net.

Answer (score 3):

Only a `UIViewController` can present another `UIViewController`. The best way of doing this would be to use a delegate to tell your `UIViewController` to present the new view

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderHistoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? OrderHistoryTableViewCell {
        cell.calling.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapCall)))
        return cell
    } else {
        return OrderHistoryTableViewCell()
    }
}

@objc func tapCall(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController:
    PackageGuidelineViewController = UIStoryboard(
        name: "Main", bundle: nil
    ).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PackageGuidelineViewController") as! PackageGuidelineViewController
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```